# Unable to add menu items in menu structure section

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, codex

I am trying to add pages to menu but when I click the button "Add to Menu" the menu structure section showing me this message "Drag each item into the order you prefer. Click the arrow on the right of the item to reveal additional configuration options" and menu items are not adding to the section. I am also adding screenshot. 
Note: There is not error in console section.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need select the menu item from the list in left hand and click into "Add To Menu" button to add all selected item to Right Hand section, where you can drag and drop to arrange.

Thanks and Regards